# Power automate: "send an http request to Sharepoint" token error

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I'm trying to use a Flow to create news links in a modern site when a new post is published to an external site's rss feed.

[image]
It appears to get the JSON content correctly but the "send an http request to SP" action fails with this error:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message": 
{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no 
expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the 
expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}
clientRequestId: 94e00dab-0fa0-42ff-bad5-1a01977e36b4
serviceRequestId: ee528d9f-9037-b000-a5d6-4561d64500a1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of the "send an http request to SP" action, I notice that there is only one underscore  in front of metadata. It should be two, like this:  `"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.RepostPage"}`.

Comment: Yep, I caught that after posting question and the upper case typo in "IS" in IsBennerImageURlExternal, and it started working. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helps you, please accept it as answer :)